# Aliens / UN / Media coverage / 90's episode

Tags: story-identification, tv, aliens

I saw this between 1996 and 2006 for sure. It was a short term video (maybe an episode? I already searched in Outer Limits, Twilight Zone and alike with no luck)

It was about an alien warning, posing humanity some kind of dilemma: If we deliver some humans for them, they would allow the rest to continue living, if we refuse to cooperate, we all would die.

I think (but not sure) that there was some kind of UN scenery (some tribute to "*To Serve Man*" for sure) and media coverage about what would our final decision be; I remember a final view of an UFO over a building or skyscraper with some kind of ray for people being abducted/delivered.

**The main thing was the dilemma for us whether to adapt and survive through betrayal or refuse and perish.**

Comment: Sounds a bit like Children of the Earth (3rd season of Torchwood) which had aliens demanding ten percent of the underage population. But that was not a short video and was a bit later (in 2009).

Comment: Sounds indeed like *Outer Limits* or one of Sci-Fi's own productions for TV. I've seen one that sounded quite similar, although I don't remember its name (probably created later than your given timeframe though).

Comment: If it wasn't a video I'd suggest "The Excalibur Alternative" by David Weber - there's a plot point about whether earth should betray a group of people to be spared by aliens (that group of people having been grabbed by, and later escaped from, said aliens) - I recall a decent bit of musing about what it would mean to make that choice - or similar kinds of choices, survival vs honor vs mercy

Comment: Yes Yes! They wanted all the black people from earth and gave them 24 hrs to decide. They wanted to use only blacks as fuel because melanin in the skin was an energy source..I was looking for that episode too it was on Outer Limits! I think the got rid of it because it was too controversial...

Answer (score 9):

It definitely sounds like Torchwood's Third Season Arc; "[Children of Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchwood:_Children_of_Earth)".

> The central storyline initially seemed like a kind of Independence Day
>   meets Children of the Damned mash-up, with every child on earth
>   periodically possessed by an evil alien race known simply as "The 456"
>   and scarily intoning "We are coming! We are coming!" over and over
>   again.
>
> Naturally Captain Jack Harkness and the Torchwood team get cracking
>   investigating the spooky goings on, and before long the British
>   government, UNIT and the US army are all involved in what has become a
>   world-wide emergency.
>
> What starts of as a seemingly standard alien invasion story turns far
>   more sinister, as it emerges the "456" are demanding to beam up - for
>   their own sinister purposes - **10% of all the children on earth**.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it could be "Cosmic Slop" episode "Space Traders" from 1994 starring Robert Guillaume. In part one, A conservative African American politician must choose between his people's survival and appeasing his white colleagues when space aliens propose to share their profound knowledge in exchange for all black people on earth.

In the ending:

> Robert Guillaume is shown being taken up to the alien spaceship via a light beam.

It is based on "The Space Traders" a science fiction short story by Derrick Bell.  The video can be found at the link below:

[IMDB Cosmic Slop Description](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109487/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

[Wiki Space Traders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Traders)

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkDVwTWloDU)